# Cro::WebSocket::Client doesn't work

Tags: raku, cro

Created a websocket server with "cro sub".

Wrote this client:

```
use v6;
use Cro::WebSocket::Client;

constant WS-PORT = '20000';
constant WS-ADDRESS = 'localhost';
constant WS-PATH = 'chat';
constant WS-URL = 'ws://' ~ WS-ADDRESS ~ ':' ~ WS-PORT ~ '/' ~ WS-PATH;
constant TIMEOUT-TO-CONNECT = 5; # seconds

my $timeout;
my $connection-attempt;

await Promise.anyof(
  $connection-attempt = Cro::WebSocket::Client.connect(WS-URL),
  $timeout = Promise.in(TIMEOUT-TO-CONNECT));

if $timeout.status == Kept
{
  say "* could not connect to server in ', TIMEOUT-TO-CONNECT, ' seconds";
  exit 1;
}

if $connection-attempt.status != Kept
{
  say "* error ", $connection-attempt.cause,
    " when trying to connect to server";
  exit 1;
}

my $connection = $connection-attempt.result;
my $peer = WS-ADDRESS ~ ':' ~ WS-PORT;
say '* connected with ', $peer;

my $counter = 0;

my $message-supplier = Supplier::Preserving.new;
my $has-message-to-send = $message-supplier.Supply;
$message-supplier.emit(1);

react
{
  whenever $has-message-to-send
  {
    $counter++;
    $connection.send($counter);
    say "* ok, sent message ", $counter, " to server"; 
  }

  whenever $connection.messages -> $reply
  {
    say '* received reply=[' ~ $reply ~ '] from server';
    $message-supplier.emit(1);
  }

} # react
```

I see with tcpdump the response code 101 (switching protocols) from the server, but I don't see the message sent from the client to the server.

So, what am I doing wrong ?

Another question, shoudn't "$connection.send" return a Promise or something ? What if there's an error when sending ?

And *another* question: it seems the server only understands IPV6 addresses...how to make it understand IPV4 addresses ?

That's it, for now.

---

UPDATE

As per Takao's advice, changing

```
$connection.send($counter)
```

to

```
$connection.send($counter.Str)
```

solves the problem (though I tried it on another program, not this one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's resolve this piece by piece.

Firstly, your code looks correct to me, except for a couple of tiny bits.

When I reproduced your code, it indeed did not work, so I tried it with `cro trace .` instead of `cro run .`. You can find info about that mode in [official docs](https://cro.services/docs/cro-tool#Tracing_Services).
The alternative way is to just set `CRO_TRACE=1` environment variable.

So during debug I saw this error:

`[TRACE(anon 1)] Cro::HTTP::ResponseParser QUIT No applicable body serializer could be found for this message`

As it says, the body you sent could not be serialized. So I looked into what are you sending: `$counter`. `$counter` in your code is `Int`, so we need to make it `Str` before, doing simple `$counter.Str` makes your example work.

Also, note that you are sending a message on every reply, and echo server (default one you created using `cro stub`) also sends a reply for every incoming message, so your example sends messages endlessly. To prevent that you may consider adding a condition under which you will no longer send things, but well, it is a test example anyway, so up to you.

As for your other questions:

> Another question, shoudn't "$connection.send" return a Promise or something?

It should not, I'll write out some cro's architecture details to explain it next. As you may know from reading [docs](https://cro.services/docs/approach), cro pipeline is basically just a bunch of `Cro::Transform`-wrapped supplies. Inside of `Cro::Websocket::Client::Connection`, `send` method just sends a thing directly into `Cro::Source` of the whole pipeline, you cannot go wrong with a simple `$supplier.emit($message)`(the real implementation of this method looks very close to this line). The thing you bumped into occurred further in the pipeline. I am sure it is not a nice user experience to hide exceptions of such cases, so I'll consider making a patch to propagate the exception, so it'd be easier to catch(although you always can use debug mode).

> it seems the server only understands IPV6 addresses...how to make it understand IPV4 addresses ?

I am not sure about that, please open a new question.